# ggplot2 geom_bar fill aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following code to graph a contracts in different countries.

```
Country <- CCOM$Principal.Place.of.Performance.Country.Name
Val <- CCOM$Action_Absolute_Value
split <- CCOM$Contract.Category

ggplot(CCOM, aes(x = Country, y = Val, fill = levels(split))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I want a simple stacked bar chart with the bars colored by the contract category which is the variable "split" (ie. CCOM$Contract.Category).

However when I run the code it produces the graph below:

[image]

Why won't gplot separate the spending into three distinct blocks?  Why do I get color sections scattered throughout the chart.?  I have tried using factor(split) and levels(split) but does not seem to work.  Maybe I am putting it in the wrong position.

Comment: Try `ggplot(CCOM, aes(x = Country, y = Val, fill = Contract.Category))`

Comment: Please add a minimal sample of your data, so the code will be reproducible.

Comment: It's ok.  when I order the dataset by the contract category, it works.  I don't know why I have to do that though.  Shouldn't need to, but in the short term the problem is solved.

Comment: You need to do it because of the weird thing you're doing defining an extra variable `split <- CCOM$Contract.Category` and then using `levels(split)` as the `fill`. If don't do those extra weird steps and use `fill = Contract.Category` as Andie suggests, you should be fine.

Comment: In the same line as @Andrie's comment, a better call should use the data frame names instead: `ggplot(CCOM, aes(x = Principal.Place.of.Performance.Country.Name, y = Action_Absolute_Value, fill = Contract.Category))`. Terribly long names, that make for a hard-to-read code, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you suggest `order` provides a solution:

```
ggplot(CCOM[order(CCOM$split), ], aes(x = Country, y = Val, fill = Contract.Category)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I have a similar example where I use the equivalent of `fill` as `Contact.Category` and it still requires the reordering.

Comment: The better solution is Andrie's comment. Creating a copy of the column and using `levels()` on the copy creates the problem. Simply using the column directly `fill = Contract.Category` skips the problem.

Comment: Can't test without OP's data, but with the simplified `fill`, the `order` should be unnecessary.

Comment: I agree but for my data it is insufficient hence providing an answer. I'd be curious to find an alternate solution but the age old adage applies

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I just realized what was going on. You seem scared to modify your data frame, don't be! Creating external vectors for `ggplot` is asking for trouble. Rather than create `Country` and `Val` as loose vectors, add them as columns to your data:

```
CCOM$Country <- CCOM$Principal.Place.of.Performance.Country.Name
CCOM$Val <- CCOM$Action_Absolute_Value
```

Then your plot is nice and straightforward, you don't have to worry about order or anything else.

```
ggplot(CCOM, aes(x = Country, y = Val, fill = Contract.Category)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```